# How to atomic store & load an interface in golang?

Tags: go, atomic

I want to write some code like this:

```
var myValue interface{}

func GetMyValue() interface{} {
    return atomic.Load(myValue)
}

func StoreMyValue(newValue interface{}) {
    atomic.Store(myValue, newValue)
}
```

It seems like that i can use **LoadUintptr(addr *uintptr) (val uintptr)** and **StoreUintptr(addr *uintptr, val uintptr)** in atomic package to achive this,but i do not know how to convert between **uintptr**,**unsafe.Pointer** and **interface{}**.

If i do it like this:

```
var V interface{}

func F(v interface{}) {
    p := unsafe.Pointer(&V)
    atomic.StorePointer(&p, unsafe.Pointer(&v))
}

func main() {
    V = 1
    F(2)
    fmt.Println(V)
}
```

the **V** will always be 1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you want [atomic Value](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#Value). You can store and fetch values atomically with it (signatures are `interface{}`  but you should put same type into it). It does some unsafe pointer stuff under the hood like what you wanted to do.

Sample from docs:

```
var config Value // holds current server configuration
// Create initial config value and store into config.
config.Store(loadConfig())
go func() {
        // Reload config every 10 seconds
        // and update config value with the new version.
        for {
                time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
                config.Store(loadConfig())
        }
}()
// Create worker goroutines that handle incoming requests
// using the latest config value.
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go func() {
                for r := range requests() {
                        c := config.Load()
                        // Handle request r using config c.
                        _, _ = r, c
                }
        }()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to use `atomic.StorePointer` and `atomic.LoadPointer` (based on your example):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync/atomic"
    "unsafe"
)

var addr unsafe.Pointer

func GetMyValue() *interface{} {
    return (*interface{})(atomic.LoadPointer(&addr))
}

func StoreMyValue(newValue *interface{}) {
    atomic.StorePointer(&addr, unsafe.Pointer(newValue))
}

func main() {
    var i interface{}
    i = 1
    StoreMyValue(&i)
    fmt.Println("before:", *GetMyValue())
    i = 2
    StoreMyValue(&i)
    fmt.Println("after", *GetMyValue())
}
```

Playground [link](https://play.golang.org/p/93Ri2RTEoC)

Note that this will not make your object thread-safe. Only the pointer is stored/loaded atomically. Also, I would avoid using `interface{}` and prefer concrete types whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using '`any`' (`interface{}`), [Go 1.19](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.19#mem) (Q3 2022) comes with [new types in the `sync/atomic` package](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.19#atomic_types) that make it easier to use atomic values, such as [atomic.Int64](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#Int64) and [`atomic.Pointer[T]`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#Pointer).

That would be easier than using [`atomic.StorePointer`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic#StorePointer).
This comes from [issue 50860 "`sync/atomic`: add typed atomic values"](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/50860).
And [CL 381317](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/381317/)

> `Pointer[T]` also avoids conversions using unsafe.Pointer at call sites.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot do this.

You will have to protect the store/load with a mutex.
The internal representation of an interface is not specified by the language and might (is) to large to be handled by package atomic.